# What's the formula to get the x² in this chi-square table?

Tags: statistics, sampling

I'm just wondering what's the formula to get the $x^2$ answers in this table:

> $$\begin{align}
> \text{expected value}&=\frac{(\text{Total of the 1st Row})(\text{Total of the 2nd Column})}{\text{Overall Total}}\\
> &=\frac{(90)(64)}{250}=23.04
> \end{align}$$
>
> Continue the computation until all the variables have expected values, compare them against the expected values below in the table, arrange for the computation of $x^2$.
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
> \text{observed}&\text{expected}&\text{observed}-\text{expected}&(\text{observed}-\text{expected})^2&x^2\\\hline
> 31&30.96&0.04&0&0\\
> 2&20.64&-18.64&347.45&16.83\\
> 53&34.4&18.6&345.96&10.06\\
> 14&23.04&-10.36&107.33&6.99\\
> 45&25.6&19.4&376.36&14.7\\
> 45&36&9&81&2.25\\
> 53&24&29&841&35.04\\
> 2&40&-38&1444&36.1\\\hline
> &&&&125.52
> \end{array}\\
> x^2=125.52$$
>
> The degree of freedom is calculated as $(\text{row}-1)(\text{column}-1)$, we have three number of rows and three number of columns hence $$\text{degree of freedom}=(\text{row}-1)(\text{column}-1)=(3-1)(3-1)=4$$
>
> Refer to the table of the critical value for the chi square, the critical value in the table for $db=4$ and a significance of $0.05$ is $9.49$.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. Just divide the $(\text{observed}-\text{expected})^2$ value by the expected value. Example: $$\frac{347.45}{20.64} = 16.83$$

Answer (score 0):

Right, those values in the column $\chi^2$ are called
"contributions to" or "components of" the overall chi-squared statistic 125.52.

I verified your table as follows:

```
 > obs = c(31,2,53,14,5,45,45,53,2)
 > exp = c(30.96,20.64,34.4,23.04,15.36,25.6,36,24,40)
 > dif = obs-exp
 > d.sq = dif^2
 > cont = dif^2/exp
 > comp = round(cont,4)
 > cbind(obs, exp, dif, dif.sq, comp)
       obs   exp    dif    dif.sq    comp
  [1,]  31 30.96   0.04    0.0016  0.0001
  [2,]   2 20.64 -18.64  347.4496 16.8338
  [3,]  53 34.40  18.60  345.9600 10.0570
  [4,]  14 23.04  -9.04   81.7216  3.5469
  [5,]   5 15.36 -10.36  107.3296  6.9876
  [6,]  45 25.60  19.40  376.3600 14.7016
  [7,]  45 36.00   9.00  961.0000  2.2500
  [8,]  53 24.00  29.00  441.0000 35.0417
  [9,]   2 40.00 -38.00 1444.0000 36.1000
 > sum(cont)
 [1] 125.5186
 > 1 - pchisq(125.52, 4)
 [1] 0
```

**Some comments on interpretation.** The area under the density curve of $Chisq(df = 4)$ to the
right of the observed value 125.52 is essentially 0. So you
certainly reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level (but
also the 0.1% level, etc.) On average, if the null hypothesis
were true, you would observe a chi-squared statistic around 4.
And as you have seen, any value above 9.5 or 10 can be
considered as evidence against the null hypothesis.

The four cells of your $3 \times 3$ contingency table
with the largest contributions to the highly significan
statistic are the ones with observed values 2, 53, 53, and
2. The cells with observed counts of 2 had far fewer
than the expected number of 'hits'. If you want to know
the 'explanation' for rejecting the null hypothesis, perhaps
look at those cells of your original table.